# Can Jmeter support 300 000 virtual users

Tags: jmeter, virtual

Is it possible with Jmeter for 300 000 virtual users(PSU) and how?.

I tried with 50 users, later for second time I was able to do only for 10 users.

Is it something with Non-GUI I should work?

Comment: Apologies for not understanding meaning of 'lakh',  I looked it up.  Do you mean scaling a load test to 300,000 users?

Comment: Exactly Richard Friedman... concurrent users is 300,000. What open source you can suggest if its not possible via jmeter.

Comment: If you hold the connection open for each user/thread (i.e. http 1.1 keep-alive) your jmeter server will not manage. You start getting issues over 1000 connections per server

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all follow [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](https://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) guide.
2. Once you have proper JMeter configuration you can figure out what maximum amount of users JMeter instance can handle.
3. Once you know how many users can be simulated with a single JMeter instance you can consider [Distributed Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) when one JMeter server orchestrates a number of JMeter slave machines and collects aggregate response.

By the way, you may not necessarily need to simulate as many as 300 000 virtual users as:

- real users don't hammer application non-stop, they need to "think" some time between operations
- time to load the page also needs to be considered

So given 300 000 users which wait for 15 seconds between requests and page load time is 5 seconds, it means that each user makes 3 requests per minute (60 / (15 think time + 5 seconds to load the page)).

Assuming above situation 300 000 users will produce 900 000 requests per minute which is 15 000 requests per second which is still high but looks more achievable.

So you can consider switching to so called "goal-oriented scenario" and focus on generating X requests per second load rather than simulating N users. You can precisely define requests per second rate using [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer).